# SQLite - How to implement a search function of sorts

Tags: sql, sqlite, web-sql

I've got an SQLite database with 2 tables.

The first one is called WORDS and has rows that look like:
  (id, word)

The second one is called WORDS2SECTION and has rows that look like: 
  (id, sectionid)

Every word in the book is listed in WORDS and has a corresponding id. 
The second table is a bunch of rows connecting each id (symbolizing a word) to a particular section of the book.

I'd like to be able to input a bunch of different words and find the sectionid numbers that contain all of those words.

If there were just one word, then I'm fine:

```
SELECT sectionid JOIN WORDS WHERE word = '%hello%'
```

My question is then, how do I expand this to be able to find the sectionid that has all of an inputted list of words.

I tried this:

```
SELECT sectionid JOIN WORDS ON WORDS.id = WORDS2SECTION.id WHERE word = '%hello%' IN (SELECT sectionid JOIN WORDS ON WORDS.id = WORDS2SECTION.id WHERE word = '%word2%')
```

But that didn't seem to work.  Any ideas?  I've search for a while trying to find a solution, but I couldn't find one yet.  Though, I admit I'm quite the novice at SQL.

Comment: There is a full-text search module available for sqlite, it could make your task a lot more efficient.  http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by `sectionid`:

```
select sectionid, count(sectionid)
from WORDS2SECTION
where id in (select id
    from WORDS
    where word in ('hello', 'foo', 'bar')
)
group by sectionid
```

If the count is the same as the number of words, you have a perfect hit. If the number is lower, some of the words were found. That way, you can weight the results.

Using `having count(sectionid) > X`, you can limit the results to those which match at least X matches.

Using `order by count(sectionid) desc` will give you the best matches first.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sectionid
  from WORDS2SECTION
 where id in (select id 
                       from WORDS
                      where word like '%hellow%');
```

Comment: The two tables are joined by `id`